# Django ImageKit: How to rename uploaded images?

Tags: python, django, image, python-2.7, image-processing

I have a photo field in my user model and I wonder how to rename the uploaded image to the user's ID?

Here is what I have right now, it will keep the image's original file name:

```
photo = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='form_photos',
        processors=[Adjust(color=0),],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 60},
        null=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean as you save the image change the file name to 'userid'.jpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change upload_to value to function like this

```
def upload_to_id_image(instance, filename):
    extension = splitext(filename)[1].lower()
    salt, hashed = generate_sha1(instance.id)
    path = 'profiles/%(id)s_%(date_now)s_' % {
                                         'id': instance.user.id,
                                         'date_now': get_datetime_now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d")}
    return '%(path)s%(hash)s%(extension)s' % {'path': path,
                                          'hash': hashed[:16],
                                          'extension': extension}
```

and then, you should change your code like this,

```
photo = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=upload_to_id_image,
```

of course you can delete hash code.
but for file security, make hashed file name is better.